# Aceessing K8s secrets from any Airflow task

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, mwaa, airflow-2.x

We have an Airflow (Celery executor) setup that can run tasks on our K8s cluster. The tasks that use KubernetesPodOperator can access K8s secrets [as described in the documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-cncf-kubernetes/stable/operators.html#how-to-use-cluster-configmaps-secrets-and-volumes-with-pod). The rest of the tasks run on Celery workers outside of the K8s cluster.

How can tasks using other operators (e.g., SqlSensor) access the same K8s secrets as the tasks using KubernetesPodOperator?

Answer (score 1):

You can map the secrets as volumes ot variables into your Worker Pods and they will be available for all tasks - either as specific directory or as environment variables.

You just have to modify the Helm Chart (or whatever deployment you use) to use those.

Comment: The Airflow workers are celery workers. Only tasks that use KubernetesPodOperator will run in the K8s cluster.

Comment: Seems you wan to get secrets from K8S to be used outside of K8S? That's a bad idea.  That makes them kind of non-secret any more. You could use kubectl command to retrieve value of secrets from K8S but for that you would need to have credentials which allows reading them (but this would make them not-secrets). Common practice is to have Celery workers run as Kubernetes Deployments. This is how the official Helm Chart of Airflow uses them: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/helm-chart/stable/index.html. Just make your Celery workers part of K8S :). This is the only good way.

Comment: Unfortunately we cannot move Airflow workers to K8s. An alternative we are looking into is using an external secret manager and integrating it with K8s and Airflow.

Comment: Yep. That one is Best. Airflow has Secret Manager support built in https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/security/secrets/secrets-backend/index.html

Answer (score 1):

If you need to pass secrets between MWAA and K8s I would suggest using an external secrets manager.

AWS Secrets Manager can be used natively by MWAA and K8S.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/connections-secrets-manager.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/specifying-sensitive-data-secrets.html

Hashicorp Vault is another option.

One thing to note is to not pass Secrets as variables to KubernetesPodOperator

---

Our solution was to actually run MWAA tasks on AWS Fargate using ECS operator

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-amazon/stable/operators/ecs.html

Secrets are shared per ECS task definition and used as environmental variables. Developers have a simple YAML configuration file for defining ECS tasks and associated secrets from AWS Secrets Manager and Terraform handles managing Task Definitions based on this YAML. It works really smooth for our particular use case.